# Find a normal vector given two vectors and an angle

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Given normals $A=(x_a, y_a,z_a)$, $B=(x_b, y_b,z_b)$, and an angle $\theta$ with $A\perp B$, how do I find a vector C such that $A\perp C$ and the angle between $B$ and $C$ is $\theta$?

Comment: Rotate $B$ about the axis defined by $A$.

Comment: Going off amd's suggestion, look at the rotation matrix necessary to do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Axis_and_angle

Comment: Look up "cross product" or "vector product" on google. :)